# iText hangs in adding element to document in WebSphere

Tags: java, pdf, itext, websphere, websphere-9

I have a legacy application that uses **itext 5.5.6** on **java 1.8.0_171 64 bit** which runs on **Websphere application server ND 9.0.5.13** and **Windows server 216 standard version 1607 64 bit**  and I am using it to convert html to pdf
I am facing an issue when there's a very large word (till 30 thousand character) entered from the end user like:

aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa....till 30 thousand character

it makes Itext hangs in the following line and not throwing any exceptions:

```
document.add(myPdfPTable)
```

This behavior doesn't happen on tomcat server

below is my code:

```
public Document generatePDF(String fontPath,String html) throws Exception {

        com.itextpdf.text.Document document = new com.itextpdf.text.Document(PageSize.A4, 20, 20, 100, 50);

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        pdfWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, baos);

        pdfWriter.setPageEvent(ppaHeaderFooter);
        pdfWriter.setViewerPreferences(PdfWriter.PageModeUseOC);
        pdfWriter.setPdfVersion(PdfWriter.VERSION_1_5);
                    
        document.open();
        document.addAuthor(authorName);
        document.addCreator(authorName);
        document.addSubject(filename);
        document.addCreationDate();
        document.addTitle(filename);
        
        Font arabicFont = FontFactory.getFont(fontPath, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, 14);
        FontFactory.register(fontPath);
        

        Font bold = FontFactory.getFont(fontPath, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, 14f, Font.BOLD);
        Font regularfont = FontFactory.getFont(fontPath, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, 10);
        List<Element>  pdfElements = getElementsFromHtml(html, fontPath);

        PdfPTable contentTable = new PdfPTable(1);
        contentTable.setRunDirection(PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL);
        contentTable.setSplitLate(false);
        contentTable.setWidthPercentage(90);
        contentTable.setExtendLastRow(true); 

        

        for (Element element : pdfElements) {
            PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
            cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
            cell.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
            cell.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
            cell.setArabicOptions(ColumnText.DIGITS_EN2AN);
            cell.addElement(element);
            contentTable.addCell(cell);
        }

        
        document.add(contentTable);
        return document;
        
}

public ArrayList<Element> getElementsFromHtml(final String html, String fontPath) throws IOException {

        final ElementList elements = new ElementList();

        StringBuilder stylefile = new StringBuilder();

        stylefile.append("body {font-size: 14pt;font-family:MyCustomFont;line-height: 1.5;dir:rtl}");
        stylefile.append("table{padding: 0px;border-spacing: 0px;font-size: 14pt;}");
        stylefile.append("td{height:30px;}");

        

        CSSResolver cssResolver = new StyleAttrCSSResolver();
        CssFile cssFile = XMLWorkerHelper.getCSS(new ByteArrayInputStream(stylefile.toString().getBytes()));
        cssResolver.addCss(cssFile);

        XMLWorkerFontProvider fontProvider = new XMLWorkerFontProvider(XMLWorkerFontProvider.DONTLOOKFORFONTS);
        fontProvider.register(fontPath, "MyCustomFont");
        CssAppliers cssAppliers = new CssAppliersImpl(fontProvider);
        HtmlPipelineContext htmlContext = new HtmlPipelineContext(cssAppliers);
        htmlContext.setTagFactory(Tags.getHtmlTagProcessorFactory());

        final ElementHandlerPipeline end = new ElementHandlerPipeline(elements, null);
        final HtmlPipeline htmlPipeline = new HtmlPipeline(htmlContext, end);
        final CssResolverPipeline cssPipeline = new CssResolverPipeline(cssResolver, htmlPipeline);

        
        final XMLWorker worker = new XMLWorker(cssPipeline, true);
        final XMLParser p = new XMLParser(worker, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

        final String resolvedHtml = "<body>" + html + "</body>";
        p.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(resolvedHtml.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"))), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

        return new ArrayList<Element>(elements);
}
```

**UPDATE1**
After enabling hung thread detection in websphere I was able to find the Hung thread cause:

```
ThreadMonitor W   WSVR0605W: Thread "WebContainer : 4" (00003bed) has been active for 672628 milliseconds and may be hung.  There is/are 1 thread(s) in total in the server that may be hung.
    at com.ibm.tivoli.itcam.gdc.data.GDCInstanceDataManager.resetProvisional(GDCInstanceDataManager.java:489)
    at com.ibm.tivoli.itcam.gdc.GDCMethodProbePoint.customProbeEndEvent(GDCMethodProbePoint.java:1691)
    at com.ibm.tivoli.itcam.toolkit.ai.boot.callbacks.generic.CustomProbeCallback.customProbeAfterCallbackInstance(CustomProbeCallback.java:450)
    at com.ibm.tivoli.itcam.toolkit.ai.boot.callbacks.generic.CustomProbeCallback.customProbeAfterCallback(CustomProbeCallback.java:409)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfFont.width(PdfFont.java:138)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfChunk.getCharWidth(PdfChunk.java:961)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.BidiLine.processLine(BidiLine.java:383)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ColumnText.go(ColumnText.java:1068)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ColumnText.go(ColumnText.java:990)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ColumnText.goComposite(ColumnText.java:1523)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ColumnText.go(ColumnText.java:996)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ColumnText.go(ColumnText.java:990)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPCell.getMaxHeight(PdfPCell.java:1044)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPTable.getFittingRows(PdfPTable.java:2141)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ColumnText.goComposite(ColumnText.java:1753)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ColumnText.go(ColumnText.java:996)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ColumnText.go(ColumnText.java:990)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ColumnText.go(ColumnText.java:978)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfDocument.addPTable(PdfDocument.java:2673)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfDocument.add(PdfDocument.java:750)
    at com.itextpdf.text.Document.add(Document.java:278)
```

**UPDATE2**: found out that finally the file is created but it takes around 15 minutes to be created while the file size is only 350 KB but it consists of 280 pages, while same request on tomcat 9 java 8 takes 30 seconds to complete so it's seems to be a Websphere issue.

**UPDATE3**: Based on comments below it maybe a monitoring issue so I disabled Performance Monitoring Infrastructure (PMI) but still facing same issue, so it maybe a JVM args config issue, so here's my JVM Args:

```
-Dcom.ibm.jsse2.overrideDefaultProtocol=TLSv12 
-Dcom.ibm.jsse2.overrideDefaultTLS=true 
-DFileNet.WSI.AutoDetectLTPAToken=true 
-Dcom.filenet.authentication.token.userid=sso:ltpa 
-Dam.wasserver=server1 
-Dam.wasnode=MyNode01 
-Dam.wasprofile=AppSrv01 
-Dam.wascell=MyNode01Cell
-Dcom.ibm.tivoli.itcam.ai.runtimebuilder.inputs=${ITCAMDCHOME}/runtime/AppSrv01.MyNode01Cell.MyNode01.server1.DCManualInput.txt  
-Dws.bundle.metadata=${ITCAMDCHOME}/runtime/wsBundleMetaData 
-Djava.security.policy=${ITCAMDCHOME}/itcamdc/etc/datacollector.policy 
-Xbootclasspath/p:${ITCAMDCHOME}/toolkit/lib/bcm-bootstrap.jar 
-Dsun.rmi.transport.connectionTimeout=300000 
-Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 
-Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000-verbosegc -Xgc:allocationSamplingGranularity=10000 
-Xhealthcenter:transport=jrmp,level=inprocess 
-agentlib:am_ibm_16=${WAS_SERVER_NAME} 
-Djava.net.preferIPv6Addresses=false 
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true 
-Dcom.ibm.cacheLocalHost=true 
-Djaxws.payload.highFidelity=true 
-Djava.security.auth.login.config=C:\FileNet\AE\config\jaas.conf.WebSphere -agentlib:getClasses
```

**JVM Custom Properties:**

[image]

Comment: *"an issue when there's a very large word (till 30 thousand character) entered from the end user"* - have you checked whether the time is spend while creating the pdf? Or might it be spend before? If the behavior diets between Websphere and Tomcat, the cause may be already in Websphere preprocessing the request...

Comment: @mkl, the application hangs on WebSphere only in this line when adding an element to a document: `document.add(myPdfPTable)` and on Tomcat it works very fine, so it's very obvious that it's a WebSphere issue, but I can't find any errors in WebSphere logs

Comment: Have you tried making thread dumps to determine in which method that really hangs? Also have you tried updating your dependencies? There are numerous updates since iText 5.5.6 for example...

Comment: @mkl, I added an update to the question

Comment: unfortunately I am not able to upgrade itext right now because this is a production issue and I need to solve it ASAP

Comment: @mkl, Currently I am thinking of workaround solution to search for any word that has length more than 1000 character for example to split it, what do you think ?

Comment: I don't know what the input HTMLs shall be. If they are meant to contain regular text, you could also reject such inputs with 1000+ character words as they hardly are words...

Comment: Concerning the problem thread you found  - it looks like some call for determining character widths is proxied by Websphere. As that call is executed many many times while splitting those extremely long words, the costs for proxying add up to the delays you observe. You may also check whether this proxying is necessary or can be turned off.

Comment: @mkl, what is the proxying you mean and how to turn it off ?

Comment: *"what is the proxying you mean and how to turn it off ?"* - I hardly have any WAS experience, so I don't know _how to turn it off_.  Concerning the proxying, have a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html

Comment: @mkl, I was able to fix it by disabling the ITCAM monitoring tool by removing its configuration from JVM arguments as mentioned in the answer below

Comment: Great!  At least a long as you don't use ITCAM for your WAS...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by the stacktrace:

```
at com.ibm.tivoli.itcam...
```

you have [ITCAM](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/iad/7.2.1?topic=i-configuring-itcam-websphere-application-server) enabled on your WebSphere server. ITCAM is a monitoring tool and it seems to be causing your issue.

If you want to disable it, see [this page](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/iad/7.2.1?topic=server-unconfiguring-websphere-application-data-collector).

Or removing the following JVM arguments:

```
-Dcom.ibm.tivoli.itcam.ai.runtimebuilder.inputs=${ITCAMDCHOME}/runtime/AppSrv01.Ry1vFnicnStg01Node01Cell.Ry1vFnicnStg01Node01.server1.DCManualInput.txt  
-Dws.bundle.metadata=${ITCAMDCHOME}/runtime/wsBundleMetaData 
-Djava.security.policy=${ITCAMDCHOME}/itcamdc/etc/datacollector.policy 
-Xbootclasspath/p:${ITCAMDCHOME}/toolkit/lib/bcm-bootstrap.jar
```

Comment: I disabled whole server monitoring as follows with no luck: `Performance Monitoring Infrastructure (PMI) > server_name > uncheck Enable Performance Monitoring Infrastructure > and under Currently monitored statistic set selected None` maybe I have to check my JVM args, please see my updated question

Comment: thanks for the very helpful insight, I was able to fix the issue by removing itcam related JVM arguments and I edited your answer to reflect that.